# How to access individual facebook feed through feedID after creation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I use facebook Graph API to create a feed for facebook from my own web site. It is successfully created and returned with an ID of the feed.

My question is, is it possible to create a link to this individual feed in facebook so that user from my web site can directly click and open that feed?

I know for twitter and foursquare this is possible, as I have done it.

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a "graph way" of doing it, but you can construct such a url given the user id/username and the post id (which you have):

> http://www.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_ID/posts/POST_ID

that url should take the user to the post.

---

## Edit

I take it back, here's the "graph way" of doing it, using the [FQL stream table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/):

```
SELECT post_id, permalink
FROM stream
WHERE post_id = "USERID_POSTID"
```

I'm not sure why the post_id is made of the user id + '_' + post id, but that's how it looks like.
You can see the user posts like so:

```
SELECT post_id, permalink
FROM stream
WHERE source_id = me()
```

([try it](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q%3DSELECT%20post_id,%20permalink%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3Dme%28%29))